# Bash script not exiting with status code 1 in Jenkins

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

When I run the below code in jenkins the error is displayed but Jenkins wont fail the job any idea ?
Jenkins output display git: 'pullllll' is not a git command. See 'git --help'. but will still execute the script. And in the end it exit with  [[ 0 -ne 0 ]]

```
if [[ ! -z "$VERBOSE_MODE" ]]

then

    git fetch 
    git checkout "$branch"
    git pulll
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
      echo "Error while pulling the code"
      exit 1
    fi
else
    git fetch branch &>/dev/null
    git checkout "$branch" &>/dev/null
    git pull &>/dev/null

    OUT=$?
    if [[ $OUT -eq 0 ]];then
       echo "pull got to success"
    else
       echo "Error2 while pulling the code"

       exit 1

    fi

fi
```

Comment: `pulll != pull`

Comment: `pulll` is indeed not a git command, neither would it be `pulllllll`. You don't fetch the files faster by adding more `l` letters.

Comment: @user17237997 Have you considered using `set -e`?

Comment: @Biffen yes i have the jenkins build just ends up been unstable.

Comment: @Jetchisel I am aware that pull != pull that was add to test the code.

Comment: @user17237997, you're aware that you have `pulll` rather than `pull` ?

Comment: @Jetchisel yes I do